# What would be the equivalent of componentDidUpdate() in Blaze?

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-blaze

How would you take the lifecycle management functions (i.e. this.state this.props) and conver those to the equivalent functionality in Blaze?

Would you create your own onChange() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the equivalent is autorun.

for example, let's say you are using a Blaze template in this manner:

```
{{> Bacon timesSmoked=getTimesSmoked}}
```

and you want it to respond when the number of times smoked changes from 1 to 2. you can reactively respond to those changes like this:

```
Template.Bacon.onCreated(function() {
    this.autorun(function() {
        let timesSmoked = Template.currentData().timesSmoked;
        // do something with the new value
    });
});
```